# Shell: why the global array can not be changed by functions in different thread

Tags: multithreading, shell

```
    #!/bin/bash
    grand()
    {
     i=$1
     GRAND_TOTAL[$i]=$2
     echo "inside function GRAND_TOTAL[$i]: ${GRAND_TOTAL[$i]}"
    }

    GRAND_TOTAL=(0 0 0 10 0)
    GRAND_TOTAL[2]=23
    echo ${GRAND_TOTAL[2]}
    echo ${GRAND_TOTAL[3]}
    grand 1 100 &
    grand 2 200 &
    wait
    echo "outside function GRAND_TOTAL[1]: ${GRAND_TOTAL[1]}"
    echo "outside function GRAND_TOTAL[2]: ${GRAND_TOTAL[2]}"
```

The result:
    23
    10
    inside function GRAND_TOTAL[1]: 100
    inside function GRAND_TOTAL[2]: 200
    outside function GRAND_TOTAL[1]: 0
    outside function GRAND_TOTAL[2]: 23

Why the global array can not be changed by functions in different thread? But it can be changed if run sequentially.

If I call the function to run sequentially

```
grand 1 100
grand 2 200
```

The result:

```
23
10
inside function GRAND_TOTAL[1]: 100
inside function GRAND_TOTAL[2]: 200
outside function GRAND_TOTAL[1]: 100
outside function GRAND_TOTAL[2]: 200
```

Comment: There are no threads in shell.

Answer (score 1):

Background processes are created using `fork()`, so they have their own copy of all process-internal memory, including (in this case) Bash variables. (See the *Bash Reference Manual*, [§3.2.3 "Lists of Commands"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), for the statement that `&` causes the command to be run in a subshell, and [§3.7.3 "Command Execution Environment"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment) for an explanation that subshells cannot affect their parent shells' execution environments.) The only workaround is to use some sort of external store, such as a named pipe or a regular file.